# How can I scan more than one page per time using DelphiTwain?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, twain

I cannot scan more than one page each time I start scanning. I use Delphi 7, DelphiTwain and Win 7.
Scanning more than 1 page is a process related to the scanner or the code of the Twain? I use for scan an HP HomeOffice 4600.
I think the software of the HP does not allow multiple pages. The Twain could solve this problem?
I'm trying to adapt an example "Simple Example" that I found in the ShowCases of the page "http://delphitwain.sourceforge.net/".

Comment: Can you show the code which you are using?

Comment: Why can't you scan more than one page ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't put tag information in the title of your question. The tag system works very well here, and doesn't need any help. We also don't use signatures here; you have an entire profile to tell us your name and anything else you'd like us to know about you. Thanks. :-) You also need to be specific here. In what way is it you "cannot scan more than one page"? What code are you using to try to do so? How is it not working? Do you have a multi-page scanner? We need details if we're going to be able to help you. Please [edit] and add them. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From TWAIN you can control whether to scan from flatbed or auto feeder. And if ADF, how many pages you want to scan per session.  Related TWAIN capabilities you can check:

- CAP_FEEDERENABLED
- CAP_AUTOFEED
- CAP_XFERCOUNT: Number of images the application is willing to accept this
  session

You can refer to the TWAIN specification [here](http://www.twain.org/component/attachments/download/3539.html).

Comment: The Twain specification will be very useful. Starting with the capabilities appointed.